# Cannot remove margin from box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, bootstrap-4

I want to place 2 divs side by side, but one of the div's has a margin that I cannot remove.

```css
.middleHolder{
 padding: 0px !important;
}

body{
 font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

.numberedTitle{
 font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
 font-size: 62px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin: 0 !important;
 width: 100px;
}

.subtitleHolder{
 display: inline-block;
}

p{
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 17px !important;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: /*#888*/;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<div class="middleHolder col-md-12">
  <div class="numberedTitle">
    <span>01</span>
  </div>
  <div class="subtitleHolder">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h3>Filler One</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using the !important function, but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: What it should look like]

I've also removed the `col-md-12` on both `numberedTitle` and `subtitleHolder` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add `display: inline-block`; to your `.numberedTitle` and no need to set margin.

sett inline block , will make you div act as an inline html tag ,but also keeps the dimension properties of block elements (like width, height ).

```css
.middleHolder{
 padding: 0px !important;
}

body{
 font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

.numberedTitle{
 font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
 font-size: 62px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.subtitleHolder{
 display: inline-block;
}

p{
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 17px !important;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: /*#888*/;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<div class="middleHolder col-md-12">
  <div class="numberedTitle">
    <span>01</span>
  </div>
  <div class="subtitleHolder">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h3>Filler One</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not because of your margin that they aren't placed side by side. It is because div is `not an inline component` unlike span, so every div by default gets produced in a new line. 
To have them align side by side you can simply add `float:left` to the div as shown below.Hope, it helps.

```css
.middleHolder{
 padding: 0px !important;
}

body{
 font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

.numberedTitle{
 font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
 font-size: 62px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 float:left;
 width: 100px;
}

.subtitleHolder{
 display: inline-block;
}

p{
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 17px !important;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: /*#888*/;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<div class="middleHolder col-md-12">
  <div class="numberedTitle">
    <span>01</span>
  </div>
  <div class="subtitleHolder">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h3>Filler One</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block;` to your `numberedTitle` class:

```css
.middleHolder{
 padding: 0px !important;
}

body{
 font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

.numberedTitle{
 font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
 font-size: 62px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin: 0 !important;
 width: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.subtitleHolder{
 display: inline-block;
}

p{
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 17px !important;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: /*#888*/;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<div class="middleHolder col-md-12">
  <div class="numberedTitle">
    <span>01</span>
  </div>
  <div class="subtitleHolder">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h3>Filler One</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `margin` appears because it's a default div behavior which means that it will act as a **block** even if you specify a value for **width**.

So you could use the bootstrap built-in class (i.e. `class="pull-left"`) in order to float the elements left side and this should resolve your problem.

```css
.middleHolder{
 padding: 0px !important;
}

body{
 font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

.numberedTitle{
 font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
 font-size: 62px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin: 0 !important;
 width: 100px;
}

.subtitleHolder{
 display: inline-block;
}

p{
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 17px !important;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: /*#888*/;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<div class="middleHolder col-md-12">
  <div class="numberedTitle pull-left">
    <span>01</span>
  </div>
  <div class="subtitleHolder pull-left">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h3>Filler One</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or either, you could just add `display: inline-block` to `.numberedTitle`.

```css
.middleHolder{
 padding: 0px !important;
}

body{
 font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

.numberedTitle{
 font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
 font-size: 62px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin: 0 !important;
 width: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.subtitleHolder{
 display: inline-block;
}

p{
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 17px !important;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: /*#888*/;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<div class="middleHolder col-md-12">
  <div class="numberedTitle">
    <span>01</span>
  </div>
  <div class="subtitleHolder">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h3>Filler One</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add display: inline-block; to your .numberedTitle

```
. numberedTitle {
display: inline-block;
}
```